# How to create a new Asset Metadata Schema Property on AEM?

Tags: adobe, aem

I'm trying to create a Custom Field to Assets Metadata. So far I could create that but I can't set a property in **Map to property**, I don't want to keep `./jcr:content/metadata/default`, I would like to call my new field of `first_custom_field`.

I've tried only re-write with `./jcr:content/metadata/first_custom_field` and Saved. However, when I try to edit this field on the Asset Metadata Form an error is triggered and doesn't save.

I guess that I need to create the new property in some place but I'm don't found the correct place.

[image]

The error when try save Asset:

[image]

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Sort of. I had to remove assets and reset the schema changes to original then make the changes again, and, in the end worked fine.